# Find all instances of a certain character and replace character & following word with hyperlink

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, replace, gsub

I'm working on a Twitter replica project for a course I'm taking and am attempting to hyperlink any instance of @username in a tweet with a hyperlink to the appropriate username's profile page. Using gsub I can get the replacement to work, but if the tweet has multiple instances of different @usernames, it replaces them all with just the first username. Here's what I have so far:

```
  def twet_link_replacer(twet)
    if twet.content.include? "@" 
      username = twet.content.match(/@(\w+)/)
      content_tag :p, twet.content.gsub!(/@(\w+)/, link_to(username, '/twets/'+username.to_s.gsub(/@/,""))).html_safe  
    else 
      content_tag :p, twet.content 
    end 
  end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are using two different regex to match the username. Combine them to get what you want.

```
def twet_link_replacer(twet)
  if twet.content.include? "@"
    content_tag :p, twet.content.gsub!(/@(\w+)/, link_to('\1', '/twets/\1')).html_safe
  else
    content_tag :p, twet.content
  end
end
```

Comment: Nailed it! Was unaware of \N function of gsub. Thanks!

Comment: I wanted to make my answer as accessible to you as possible so I minimally changed what you had to make it work. Please see Jordan's answer though for a cleaner way to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing way too much work here. There's no reason to call `twet.content.include? "@"` when you're using `gsub`, because `gsub` will just do nothing if `@` isn't found. You don't need the `if...else`, either, for the same reason. Something like this will suffice:

```rb
def twet_link_replacer(twet)
  new_content = twet.content.gsub(/@(\w+)/) do |username|
    link_to(username, "/twets/#{$1}")
  end

  content_tag :p, new_content
end
```

This uses a block argument to `gsub`, letting us replace matches with the result of `link_to`. Inside the block, `username` is the entire matched text (e.g. `"@Jordan"`) and `$1` is the first (and only) capture group (e.g. `"Jordan"`).

There are a couple other issues with your code. First of all, *do not* use `html_safe` on user input. I'm assuming that `twet.content` comes from user input, and so is inherently unsafe. By trusting it (which is what `html_safe` implies—it tells Rails, "do not escape this string because I believe it is safe") you're making your app wide open to XSS attacks.

Second, when you're using string concatenation or interpolation (e.g. `"/twets/" + username` or `"/twets/#{username}"`) to create a URL or path to give to `link_to`, you're probably making a mistake. It depends on what your routes look like, but if you're using [resourceful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default), which you should, then e.g.

```rb
# instead of this...
link_to(username, "/users/" + username)

# you can just do this...
link_to(username, user_path(username))
```

...which will automatically generate a URL for you, and if you change your routes later on you won't have to change your views or helpers because `user_path` will change automatically along with the routes.

Again, this depends on how you've defined your routes, but it's the direction you should try to go.

Comment: Thank you both. I'm new to Ruby and Rails, so any advice is much appreciated. Like you said Jordan, this solution is even more efficient.

Comment: @user3885689 I've added a few more notes. I highly recommend reading the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/) (the ones under "Models," "Views," and "Controllers," at least). They're short and pack a ton of really essential information.

Comment: @Jordan thank you for the thorough explanation. I just need to ask you for more explanation about the `$1` and how to works I tried different values like `$2` and `$'` and I got different result but I am unable to understand what these symbol mean.

Comment: @MoustafaSallam In a regular expression, parentheses (`(` and `)`) create "capture groups". If, for example, we were to execute the regular expression `/(\w+) and (\w+)/` against the string `"Eat peas and carrots!"`, the first group would "capture" `"peas"`, and the second would capture `"carrots"`. In Ruby, those "captures" are stored in the global variables `$1` and `$2`, respectively. Ruby defines other variables, too, like ``$` `` and `$'`, which store the text before (`"Eat "`) and after (`"!"`) the match, respectively.

Comment: I highly recommend reading the [documentation for Regexp](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html), which describes all of this and more. There's also a great tool called [Rubular](http://rubular.com/r/MaF2v1UdjF) that lets you play with Ruby's Regular expressions online. [The Pickaxe](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/intro.html#S5) also has a great sections on regular expressions (and is an all-around great, free book for beginning Rubyists).

Comment: @Jordan Thank you, I need to go deeper into learning regex, now I understand grouping thank you again.